# How-to: Dockerfile layer(s) reuse / reference

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to create a few images where each dockerfile will include some common layers. Its all mixed and no consistent sequence for all of the images.
E.g. some will need to have java on them, and I want to define the below lines (taken from the official java 8 dockerfile) as a building block (layer) that will be referenced in other dockerfiles.

In some cases it could be more than one layer that I would want to reuse - making this requirement recursive in nature (building blocks constructed of building blocks).

```
RUN \
    echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections && \
    add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer
```

Is that supported by Docker today? Is it a good practice to install e.g. Java separately as a layer that way ... or should I merge it with other installs (to keep the image minimal)? What are the best practices around such a scenario please?

=========== UPDATE ==============

Seems like the feature of referencing/including is not supported. But I am still not sure about the best practices ...

@Sri pointed out below to the best practices:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#run

Where is it encouraged to use "RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y" for all package installation.

But does it also mean that we are not encouraged to use different layers for different packages? like the below example:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y package-foo
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y package-bar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on further reading:

1. There is no INCLUDE like feature currently. https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/735
2. Best practices encourage to use "RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y" for all package installation. But it doesn't mean that you can not use that same technique to separate package installs (e.g. package-foo and package-bar) due to maintainability. It is a tradeoff with minimizing the number of layers. https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#/minimize-the-number-of-layers (see also how the build cache operates, identifying it as different layers)

Thank you @Sri for some lead pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Docker has the concept of base image. This can be provided in the Dockerfile as "FROM < base-image >". This should be the first line in the Dockerfile. The base image can contain all the commons and individual containers can deal with specific functionalities.

Comment: Hi @Sri , I am aware of the base image and "FROM" directive. As my question mentions though I am portraying a scenario where the layer(s) are not directly at the bottom of the stack (or right above it). Thank you.

Comment: Using "\", yes it is supported.

Comment: thanks again. Can you please link to a documentation or example using that?

Comment: Some references and recorded issues: 1. https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#run 2. https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16058.

Comment: So basically if I understood the best practices document it is not supported really and the recommendation is to merge apt commands as much as possible to keep the number of layers low. Thank you. Will wait for maybe other replies and then close.

Comment: actually I am not sure about my above statement it could be that it is just for the same packages that you need "RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y". will add to the question.